# any improvements to SQL query with subquery of view?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am returning 250,000 records in about 1:10 seconds... too long for a Job?

I feel like SQL Server should be faster..

```
SELECT ColOne 
    FROM TableA WITH (nolock) 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ColOne 
                        FROM VIEW_1 WITH (nolock) 
                         WHERE LastDate < GETDATE() - 30)
```

Any ways to improve the speed? Or am I making an error?

*EDIT
To clear up any questions regarding the view - there is a potential that VIEW_1 has more than one record for ColOne.

The View SQL:

```
    SELECT MAX(LastSeen) AS LastSeenDate, IDValue 
FROM dbo.IDValueTable_LASTSEEN WITH (nolock) 
WHERE (LastSeen IS NOT NULL) AND EXISTS (SELECT IDValue 
    FROM dbo.IDValueTable WITH (nolock)) GROUP BY IDValue
```

**UPdate
I believe this to be the working query ( I still need to confrim there are not more or less records to be found )

`SELECT DISTINCT IDValue FROM dbo.IDValueTable_LASTSEEN WITH (nolock) 
 WHERE (LastSeen IS NOT NULL) AND (LastSeen < GETDATE() - 30) 
 AND IDValue IN (SELECT IDValue FROM dbo.IDValueTable WITH (nolock))`

We need to apply both DISTINCT and yous IN not EXISTS

Comment: I might be missing the point, but why do you need to put the condition inside the sub query? Wouldn't it be better just do a select from the view with an inner join to the main table?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with this query. If condition EXISTS then you get full `TableA` select if not EXISTS you just return nothing. Also What is the VIEW maybe you can optimize this query using tables instead of View.

Comment: In the original query, is TableA the IDValueTable from the View? and so ColOne would be IDValue? Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the tables from the View are the ones also in the select I would suggest.

Add an index to table dbo.IDValueTable_LASTSEEN for the field LastSeen.

Forget about the VIEW, is not adding value in this case and it actually slows the query (why calculate the max of lastseen if later you are already filtering it).

Use following SELECT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDValue 
  FROM dbo.IDValueTable_LASTSEEN WITH (nolock) 
  WHERE (LastSeen IS NOT NULL) 
   AND (LastSeen < GETDATE() - 30) 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT IDValue 
                 FROM dbo.IDValueTable WITH (nolock))
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortuantely I am getting 845,396 records this way. I think it should be down around 20k records.

Comment: The original query before I edited it did not have the DISTINCT, did you run it with or without it? Also I have removed the GROUP BY, as we are not calculating anything was completely useless. This should give you the number of different IDs that have been seen in the last 30 days.

Answer (score 2):

As @valex points out in his comment I think youe `EXISTS` condition is wrong.  If a record exists where `LastDate < GETDATE() - 30` then you'll get the whole table back - otherwise you'll get nothing.

I think you want (with table names added for clarity)

```
SELECT ColOne 
    FROM TableA WITH (nolock) 
    WHERE TableA.ColOne IN (
        SELECT VIEW_1.ColOne 
        FROM VIEW_1 WITH (nolock) 
        WHERE LastDate < GETDATE() - 30)
```

The main performance improvements here would be indexes on `LastDate` and `ColOne`

Comment: Wouldn't just "SELECT VIEW_1.ColOne FROM VIEW_1 WHERE LastDate < GETDATE() - 30" would return exactly same result?

Comment: As written, yes - I have a feeling that the columns are _not_ the same between the two tables but the obfuscation makes it look that way.

Comment: @pedromarce This alone returns -- 841,192 records -- 6:23 seconds There are more than one records for ColOne

Comment: @JoJo are there indexes on `LastDate` and/or `ColOne`?

Comment: @DStanley no Indexes - I am just now learning to create views. I have updated my question by showing the VIEW SQL

Comment: @JoJo Indexes are going to impact performance much more that tweaking a query or view definition.

Comment: @DStanley Si~ I suggested to my Lead that we should put an index on the View (esspecially since it has such a huge return) he said it was fine as is.. I am still inclined to index the view. I know a little bit about it's benefits.

Comment: I'd put the index on the _table_ that the view is pulling from - you should get the same benefit.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to address the first part of the question briefly - "too long for a job?"

This depends on your particular implementation. Are you running it from a network server, or as a local instance? Hardware, network traffic, server utilization, etc. can all impact your execution time.

For example: My company just upgraded the boxes that house our SQL Databases. With 250+ employees at this location, my experience of the performance improvements is marginal at best. I'd say the advice above should help.

Comment: Using the `exists` clause will really be more fast than the joins in case of huge amount of data rows stored in the tables. You can try to increase performance by checking the indexes on the tables on which the view is build.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the tables instead:

```
SELECT a.ColOne 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN VIEW_1 b ON a.ColOne = b.ColOne
WHERE b.LastDate < GETDATE() - 30;
```

Comment: This may return more records than expected if `VIEW_1` has duplicate values for `ColOne`

Answer (score 0):

Joining should work faster:

```
SELECT a.ColOne 
FROM TableA AS a
     INNER JOIN VIEW_1 AS b 
     ON a.ColOne = b.ColOne AND b.LastDate < GETDATE() - 30;
```

Comment: This may return more records than expected if `VIEW_1` has duplicate values for `ColOne`